# SQL Server 2014 Analysis Services Deploy Permission Error

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2014

How can I resolve this permissions error when deploying an Analysis Services cube? The user already has SA privileges on the localhost server.

```
------ Build started: Project: FerrariRusso, Configuration: Development ------
Started Building Analysis Services project: Incremental ....
Dimension [Date] : Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions.
Dimension [Customer] : Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions.
Dimension [Product] : Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions.
Build complete -- 0 errors, 3 warnings
------ Deploy started: Project: FerrariRusso, Configuration: Development ------
Performing an incremental deployment of the 'FerrariRusso' database to the 'localhost' server.
Generating deployment script...
   Add Database FerrariRusso
   Process Database FerrariRusso
Done
Sending deployment script to the server...
Error -1055391738 : Either the 'ACMECorp\tarzan' user does not have permission to create a new object in 'ACTARZAN-WIN81', or the object does not exist.
Deploy complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: When you say the account already has SA privileges on the localhost server, are you talking about on the database engine or the SSAS instance? Did you add that user as an administrator on the Analysis Services instance? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174561.aspx

Comment: I was talking about the database engine. Thank you for the link. It lead to the solution which was to: run SSMS as administrator > open the SSAS instance in the Object Explorer > go to Properties > Security > add the user as an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user you are deploying with is not a member of the Analysis Serices administrators group, you can modify role membership using the following procedure.

1. Run SQL Server Management Studio as administrator
2. Open the Analysis Services server in the Object Explorer
3. Go to Properties
4. Go to Security
5. Add the user as an administrator.